# Simple Merge Sort in Java

Tags: java, stack-overflow, mergesort

I'm trying to create a simple merge sort program within Java. I feel like it should work but when I go to run it I get a stack overflow error:

```
Stack overflow at MergeSort.mergeSort(MergeSort.java:24)
```

I have seen several other people on here have similar problems with such code but am struggling to fix mine. Any help would be appreciated.

Main code:

```java
import static java.lang.System.*;
import java.util.Arrays;        

public class MergeSort {

    private static int passCount;

    public static void mergeSort(Comparable[] list)
    {
        passCount = 0;
        mergeSort(list, 0, list.length);
    }

    private static void mergeSort(Comparable[] list, int front, int back)  //O( Log N )
    {
        int mid = (front + back) / 2;
        if (mid == front)
            return;
        mergeSort(list, front, mid);
        mergeSort(list, front, back);
        merge(list, front, back);
    }

    private static void merge(Comparable[] list, int front, int back)  //O(N)
    {
        Comparable[] temp = new Comparable[back - front];

        int i = front;
        int j = (front + back) / 2;
        int k = 0;
        int mid = j;

        while (i < mid && j < back)
        {
            if (list[i].compareTo(list[j]) < 0)
            {
                temp[k] = list[i];
                k++; i++;
            }
            else
            {
                temp[k] = list[j];
                k++; i++;
            }

            while(i < mid)
            {
                temp[k++] = list[i++];
            }

            while (j < back)
            {
                temp[k++] = list[j++];
            }

            for (i = 0; i < back - front; ++i)
            {
                list[front + i] = temp[i];
            }

            out.println("pass " + passCount++ + " " + Arrays.toString(list) + "\n");
        }
    }
}
```

My runner:

```java
public class MergeSortRunner
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        MergeSort.mergeSort(new Comparable[]{ 9, 5, 3, 2 });
        System.out.println("\n");

        MergeSort.mergeSort(new Comparable[]{ 19, 52, 3, 2, 7, 21 });
        System.out.println("\n");

        MergeSort.mergeSort(new Comparable[]{ 68, 66, 11, 2, 42, 31});
        System.out.println("\n");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know that this is really really late, but I have the correct answer you are looking for!

```
import static java.lang.System.*;
import java.util.Arrays;        

public class MergeSort{

private static int passCount;

public static void mergeSort(int[] list)
{
    passCount=0;
    mergeSort(list, 0, list.length);
}

private static void mergeSort(int[] list, int front, int back)  //O( Log N )
{
    int mid = (front+back)/2;
    if(mid==front) return;
    mergeSort(list, front, mid);
    mergeSort(list, mid, back);
    merge(list, front, back);

}

private static void merge(int[] list, int front, int back)  //O(N)
{
   int dif = back-front;
   int[] temp = new int[dif];
   int beg = front, mid = (front+back)/2;
   int saveMid = mid;
   int spot = 0;

   while(beg < saveMid && mid < back) {
      if(list[beg] < list[mid]) {
         temp[spot++] = list[beg++];
      } else {
         temp[spot++] = list[mid++];
      }
   }
   while(beg < saveMid)
      temp[spot++] = list[beg++];
   while(mid < back)
      temp[spot++] = list[mid++];
   for(int i = 0; i < back-front; i++) {
      list[front+i] = temp[i];
   }
    System.out.println("pass " + passCount++ + " " + Arrays.toString(list) + "\n");
  }
 }
```

Here is the runner:

```
    public class MergeSortRunner {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    MergeSort.mergeSort(new int[]{9,5,3,2});
    System.out.println();

    MergeSort.mergeSort(new int[]{19,52,3,2,7,21});
    System.out.println();

    MergeSort.mergeSort(new int[]{68,66,11,2,42,31});
    System.out.println();
   }
}
```

As it turns out, using while loops to loop through the list can help you return the proper values!

Comment: I don't know what compelled you to answer my poorly question after so many years, nor what made you do it knowing that you would receive very little attention from your efforts, but I have to feel that it comes from a sincere desire to spread knowledge and to educate those who seek answers no matter how many or small. You are a good man and I greatly appreciate you taking the time to answer my query after so many years! Keep on doing your thing and thanks again for the help!

Comment: I totally forgot I answered this, I was taking an AP Computer Science class at my high school and we did something similar to this, I just thought I would modify it for you so you could gain a better understanding! Thanks for the vote and for marking it as correct!

Answer (score 2):

You need to change:

```
mergeSort(list, front, back);
```

To:

```
mergeSort(list, mid, back);
```

It's going to result in an infinite call to `mergeSort` because you don't change any of the input parameters between calls.

You will also probably want to change:

```
if(mid==front) return;
```

to:

```
if(back - front <= 1) return;
```

Also, your implementation choice for this algorithm is likely going to result in a non-stable sort, since you are modifying the list in place. A better option would be to have `mergeSort` return a list of whatever it is you're sorting, and then implement `merge` to take two lists as arguments, and then produce a single, merged list.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Doing that gets rid of the stack overflow error. It's now going through the code but is still not sorting them right. Feeding in "9,5,3,2" sorts it to "5, 5, 3, 2" in the 1st pass, "5, 5, 2, 2" in the 2nd, and "2, 5, 2, 2" in the 3rd, which obviously means I haven't set it up right. Thanks again for the help, I'll post again once I've figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change

```
if(mid==front) return;
```

To

```
if(back-front<=1) return;
```